# Dispatched action in redux is canceled when an action is dispatched twice

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am facing an issue where I'm dispatching an action twice in my `useEffect` with different payloads. Both actions are correctly dispatched but only the second one executes my epic function.

Here is my `useEffect`

```
  useEffect (() => {
    dispatch (actions.getDashboardData ({
      viewKey: DASHBOARD_KINDS.PUBLISHER,
      widgetKey: DASHBOARD_WIDGETS.KEY_METRICS,
      isOldData: false,
      data: {
        metrics: query.metrics,
        dimensions: query.dimensions,
        interval: {
          begin: "2023-05-27T00:00:00",
          end: "2023-05-31T00:00:00"
        }
      }
    }))
    dispatch (actions.getDashboardData ({
      viewKey: DASHBOARD_KINDS.PUBLISHER,
      widgetKey: DASHBOARD_WIDGETS.KEY_METRICS,
      isOldData: true,
      data: {
        metrics: query.metrics,
        dimensions: query.dimensions,
        interval: {
          begin: "2023-05-23T00:00:00",
          end: "2023-05-27T23:00:00"
        }
      }
    }))
  }, [])
```

Below is my Epic function

```
const getDashboardDataEpic = (action$, state$) => action$
  .pipe (
    ofType (types.GET_DASHBOARD_DATA),
    switchMap (({ payload }) => {
      const { api, session } = state$.value

      const { data, widgetKey, viewKey, isOldData } = payload

      console.log ("Processing...", payload)

      const httpPayload = {/**Payload Data**/}

      return pipe ([
        setMethod (HTTP_METHOD.POST),
        setPath (API_ENDPOINTS.DASHBOARD_SEARCH),
        send (httpPayload)
      ]) (api)
        .pipe (
          map ((http) => {

            return actions.getDashboardDataSuccess ({
              data: http.response,
              //..remaining data
            })
          }),
          catchError (http => {
            // Error handling
          }
          )
        )
    })
  )

export default combineEpics (
  getDashboardDataEpic
)
```

As mentioned earlier, both are correctly dispatched but at the end only the second dispatch executes the epic function

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`switchMap()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) enforces that only one inner observable is subscribed to at any given time. So when you dispatch the second action before the inner observable  http request has finished it unsubscribes from that first inner observable. If you instead want them to run concurrently you can use `mergeMap()`. If you want to them run sequentially, use `concatMap()`.